# Form collection is not being received by actionresult; what can I do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to receive a form collection from my view to the controller and then create a record with the form collection information and introduce in my database model, but for some reason, even my actionresult is not being fired

This is the controller actionresult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CrearOperacion(FormCollection operacion)
{        
    Entities model = new Entities();
    Transacciones transaccion = new Transacciones();

    string divisa = operacion["par_divisa"];
    string user_id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    transaccion.DIVISA = divisa;
    transaccion.ID_USER = user_id;

    model.Transacciones.Add(transaccion);
    model.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Este es el HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/CrearOperacion">
   <input type="text" name="par_divisa"/>
</form>
```

Comment: When you submit the form, does `divisa` contain the expected value? Does the browser redirect you to "index"? If none of these things happen, what exactly happens when you submit the form now?

Answer (score 0):

Your input must be of type `submit` instead of `text`.

A form should have an input with `submit` type if you want to POST your information from your form to the controller method. Since it lays in a form element, it goes up into the hierarchy and will behave as you configured it (POST and to your desired URL).

Comment: I have a button below that i forgot to include in the question, and that one is of type "Submit" the problem is when i click on that is not going to index and my sql table is no adding the row

Answer (score 0):

Try change your HTML script to the below

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("CrearOperacion","Home")">
   <input type="submit" name="par_divisa"/>
</form>
```